# gazebo plugin with ros electric

Tags: gazebo, plugin, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem creating a Gazebo plugin for ros electric. 
On the Wiki I can only find the tutorial for Ros Fuerte, but I should use elctric.
Anyone can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50368/gazebo-plugin-with-ros-electric/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

ROS Electric comes with an old version of Gazebo, which uses controllers not plugins.


Some reading material: [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller) [this](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-svn-html/tutorial_controller.html).

Although maybe you can install from source a newer version of Gazebo (>1.0) which is better documented and easier to use. I'm not sure though if it will work with electric.

Cheers,

---

Originally posted by [Andrei Haidu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1419/andrei-haidu/) with karma: 146 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1